# Related video Configuration not working for Product Video

Tags: magento2, configuration, magento-community

I have retained 'No' for 'Related Video' in Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Product Video >

But, after I play the video on Product page, the related videos are displayed.

Is this a bug? How to fix this? 
[image: Configuration Section for Product Video]

Have run command:

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

[image: Related Video Shown]

[image: Related Video Slider on pause]

Comment: Clean the cache. Run command : php bin/magento c:f

Comment: @ChiragParmar Yes, have run the command. Still after video ends, Related video grid comes up.

Comment: So the issue is related videos ? When you pause or stop video, related videos are come. Is this issue ?

Comment: @ChiragParmar Yes, as mentioned in title issue is with Related video... even though I have retained 'No' setting for Related Video, they are still showing.

Comment: I tried many things. youtube settings for related videos "No" is not working.

Comment: @ChiragParmar So, it is a bug then? The magento configuration doesnt take effect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101869/discussion-between-chirag-parmar-and-shailesh).

Answer (score 0):

For related videos issue, you have to set its **height= 289px**. This **289px height** **solved my problem**. I hope it will help you too also.

Comment: Is it working for you @Shailesh ?

Comment: As mentioned in our personal chat, for this workaround... will  have to reduce height in the expanded gallery view too, which will not gel well.

Comment: Yes. I know it. But I think there is no other option for it.

Comment: There should be, I hope Magento Team looks into this. As Product video is an important section and if other videos show up there, that would be misleading to the Users.

Comment: Its not magento problem. Its youtube problem.

Comment: I think it is a Magento feature problem, as "enable/disable related video" is an explicit feature in Magento. And it is not working.... However, it is true that the cause of it is youtube is ignoring the API setting for no related video..